# find the maximum i & j using for loops

Tags: php

find the best combination of maximum value of i & j, but not exceed amount , any ideas?

```
$amount = 20000; 
$max_area = 1000; 

for ($i=0; $i<=100; $i+=0.1) { 

   for ($j=0; $j<=100; $j+=0.1) { 

       $area = $i*$j; 
       $cost = $i*1200 + ($i+$j*2) * 2500; 

       if($cost > $amount && $area > $max_area) { 
           break; 
       } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe ask on http://math.stackexchange.com/ to find a formula for this?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off finding a parametrized formula that gives you a measurement of 'efficiency' of any particular i and j, and then use analytic methods to find the absolute maximum, again parametrized. You can do all this on paper. Then translate the resulting formula to PHP.

Comment: Agreed, this looks like something you should bust out the graph paper for. Or Wolfram Alpha, whichever works for you...

Answer (score 0):

You are just trying to implement a constrained optimization problem solver.

If you take the code away for a minute, let's examine it together.

Your model looks like being the following (if you provided background information that could be useful)

> cost = 1200*i + 2*(i+j)+2500
>
> area = i*j
>
> to be maximized, constrained to
>
> cost < max_amount (but you typed cost>amount in your if statement)
>
> area > max_area

You should use an analytical method to solve it. Since it's not simple enough to be solved with simplex (because it's not linear), you must go for [heuristics](http://www.google.it/search?q=heuristic+optimization&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ait%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)